# Clojure reset(ing) multiple atoms at once

Tags: concurrency, clojure, thread-safety

Suppose foo and bar are atoms.

```
; consistent.
(reset! foo x)
; inconsistent x and y combination.
(reset! bar y)
; consistent.
```

Is it possible to reset them at once so that no other thread can see this inconsistency? Or is it necessary to bundle x and y into an atom instead of having x and y themselves being atoms?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For coordinated updates to multiple references, you want to use [refs](http://clojure.org/refs), not atoms. Refs can only be modified inside a transaction, and Clojure's STM (software transactional memory) ensures that all operations on refs succeed before committing the transaction, so all threads outside the transaction see a consistent view of the refs.

```
 (def foo (ref :x))
 (def bar (ref :y))
 (dosync
    (ref-set foo :x1)
    (ref-set bar :y1))
```

In this example, the transaction (delineated by `dosync`) will be retried if either ref was modified by a transaction in another thread, ensuring that other threads see a consistent view of `foo` and `bar`.

There is overhead in using STM, so the choice of using coordinated refs vs. a single atom that encapsulates all your mutable state will depend on your exact usage.

Answer (score 3):

From the [Clojure website's page on atoms](http://clojure.org/atoms) (emphasis added):

> Atoms provide a way to manage shared, synchronous, **independent** state.

This means that each `atom` is independent of each other, and therefore a set of `atom`s cannot be updated atomically.

You can combine both items into a single `atom`.  But you also may want to consider [`ref`s](http://clojure.org/Refs), which provide for transactional updates of multiple items:

> transactional references (Refs) ensure safe shared use of mutable storage locations via a software transactional memory (STM)